# How do I redirect a naked (apex) domain to www using Route 53?

Tags: redirect, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-route53

I need to do a 301 redirect from example.com to www.example.com using Route 53 (and S3 if necessary). There are a few solutions for similar problems but they either do not address how to [redirect from the apex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115799/set-up-dns-based-url-forwarding-in-amazon-route53) or they simply [don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370393/amazon-route-53-setup-and-301-redirection-setup).

When I follow the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115799/set-up-dns-based-url-forwarding-in-amazon-route53), Route 53 tells me I can't add a CNAME to the apex domain. Therefore, I'm stuck in the mud.

This seems dumb simple but Amazon is making it hard. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: HTTPS: see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/67222388

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try making an alias record instead of CNAME.

Per this answer:
[RRSet of type CNAME with DNS name foo.com. is not permitted at apex in zone bar.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215729/rrset-of-type-cname-with-dns-name-foo-com-is-not-permitted-at-apex-in-zone-bar)

Comment: "The one exception is when you want to redirect queries from the zone apex (such as example.com) to a record in the same hosted zone that has a type of CNAME (such as zenith.example.com). "

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html

Answer (score 98):

I just managed to figure this out yesterday:

1. Go to your S3 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home and click **Create bucket**. For **Bucket name** enter in your naked domain name, e.g. for www.example.com, you would put just example.com. Then click **Create**.
2. Click on the name of the new bucket, then click **Properties** > **Static website hosting**. On the menu that appears select **Redirect requests**. For **Target bucket or domain** enter in the full domain, such as www.example.com. For **Protocol** put in the desired protocol, http or https. Click **Save**.
3. Open your Route 53 hosted zone by navigating to https://console.aws.amazon.com/route53/home and clicking **Hosted zones** in the menu to the left. Select your domain and click on **Create Record Set**. Leave the **Name** area blank, and leave the default type at **A - IPv4 address**. Select **Yes** for Alias, and click on the **Alias Target** textbox. You may have to wait a few moments for the values in the dropdown menu that appears to populate. At this point the menu should contain the S3 Website Endpoint you created in steps 1 and 2. Select it.

Lastly, click **Create**, and enjoy your new routing set-up!

Comment: To get this to work with SSL as well (https://example.com redirecting to https://www.example.com), see this blog post: http://building.vts.com/blog/2015/11/02/route53-ssl-naked-domain-redirect/

Comment: The downside with this is that you lose your header information (referrer, etc).

Comment: Is there another way to do this that preserves the HTTP headers?

Comment: @Flimm I didn't try it but the same article is on medium and someone commented that cloudfront doesn't allow that any more. I only note that here because it may save you/someone else some time. **but** I haven't tried so I am not sure

Comment: I wrote an in-depth article with how to do this currently even with cloudfront and a private S3 bucket. https://medium.com/@kylecalicast/production-level-static-sites-in-aws-39573c9bf4d5

Comment: To have a holistic coverage of all the required redirects for HTTP and HTTP, naked and www (all 4 cases), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67222388

Comment: Yep, Route53 -> CloudFront (with naked ssl cert) -> Either S3 Static Site Redirect or Lambda Redirect is still the only way to properly do this... hours of work

Answer (score 4):

If you are using an Application Load Balancer, they added support for redirects.  You point your zone apex at your ELB (using an Alias) and have ELB do the redirect to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

This seems like a much better solution than setting up a bucket, adding static hosting, redirect, etc.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/07/elastic-load-balancing-announces-support-for-redirects-and-fixed-responses-for-application-load-balancer/

Comment: [+/-] **Pro:** You can preserve the query.  **Cons:** 1) S3 Buckets are free/very cheap, but ELB is at least $15/mo.  2) Also, piggybacking on existing ELB might not be a great idea in terms of handling all sorts of requests in one place.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on @omikes's response with an explanation and SSL support.

Ideally you want all of the following URLs to resolve to the same place:

- http://example.com
- https://example.com
- http://www.example.com
- https://www.example.com

For [technical reasons](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/apex-domains), DNS CNAME records (sometimes called ALIAS or ANAME) should be preferred over A records to point to the root (sometimes called apex/bare/naked) domains. While [some providers](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-root-domain) support this, AWS Route 53 does not.

Therefore an ideal AWS setup routes all the above to https://www.example.com.

This can be done at no extra cost but requires some extra pieces of infrastructure (~15 min setup). Unless noted use default config.

**1, S3 Bucket to redirect to `www.` subdomain**

- Create a S3 Static Hosting Website and have it redirect to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).
- Use `https` protocol.

**2, SSL certificate in Certificate Manager**

- Create for both example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

**3, CloudFront distribution**

- Use 'Redirect HTTP to HTTPS'
- As origin use the full domain of the S3 bucket. Do not select the bucket from the lsit but use the actual domain. E.g. `example.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`
- For Alternate Domain Names provide example.com
- Provide SSL certificates created previously

**4, DNS record in Route53**

- A Alias record of example.com pointing to CloudFront
- CNAME record of [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) pointing to the service

Comment: Now that we are in the IPv6 era, if you happen to have an `AAAA` record configured for `example.com` in your hosted zone, maybe it got pulled over when you transferred the domain?, then you should ensure that it **also** points to CloudFront. Otherwise you will get very confused when the redirection seems to randomly fail for days and may experience intense urges to punch the internet in the face. [source, actual experience]

Answer (score 3):

The necessary steps are as follows:

- Create a new Bucket and call it exactly as your naked domain name (eg: example.com).
- In the Bucket properties, select "Static Website Hosting" and make it redirect to your www.example.com domain. Click "save".
- Go to your Route53 hosted zone, and create an A record. Mark it as an Alias, and from the dropdown select your recently created bucket.
- You're ready.

Comment: Note: This method only works for HTTP - HTTPS does not work

Comment: For HTTPS you need to use cloudfront

Comment: With cloudfront, you can use lambda edge function to ALWAYS redirect to the correct domain

Comment: To have a holistic coverage of all the required redirects for HTTP and HTTP, naked and www (all 4 cases), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67222388

Answer (score -3):

For those who need to redirect a naked domain example.com to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

The best practice is to create a new Load Balancer

with Listener on port `80 http` that redirect 301 to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

In case you have `https` running just add another listener on port 443 that redirect 301 to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

[image]

Once you have finished with the listeners go to

`Route 53 > your domain> Create Record`

that points your new load balancer with the redirect listeners

record name: example.com

Record Type: A

Alias: Yes

Alias to Application and Load Balancer...

Select your location

Select your new Load Balancer

[image]

Save it and wait some minutes and now all request for naked example.com redirect 301 to www.example included for https request.

Note:
If you want to redirect http request to https request you need to do the same procedure but instead of a redirect listener you need to set-up a forward listener to https.