# Route 53 redirect https://domain.com to https://www.domain.com

Tags: redirect, https, dns, amazon-route53

We use an [S3 bucket and Route 53 alias record](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28978783/3145800) to redirect `domain.com` to `www.domain.com` on a DNS level. This works with http, but does not work with https requests.
There are TXT and MX records for domain.com, so we [cannot use a CNAME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215729/rrset-of-type-cname-with-dns-name-foo-com-is-not-permitted-at-apex-in-zone-bar). The `www.domain.com` is a CNAME to our Elastic Beanstalk server.
The `domain.com` cannot be an A record since the server's IP address is not fixed.
What works:

- curl http://domain.com => 301 redirect to http://www.domain.com
- curl http://www.domain.com => 301 redirect to https://www.domain.com
- curl https://www.domain.com => served by the EB server

What does not work:

- curl https://domain.com => curl: (7) Failed connect to domain.com:443; Connection refused

How to redirect https://domain.com to https://www.domain.com? Or alternatively what should we do with the TXT and MX records so we can use a CNAME record?

Comment: Instead of pointing `domain.com` to an Amazon S3 bucket for redirect, can you use the Route 53 `ALIAS` function to point to the Elastic Load Balancer that was created by Elastic Beanstalk? See: [Mapping Domain Names with name.com, Elastic Beanstalk, Elastic Load Balancer and AWS Route 53](http://compositecode.com/2014/01/23/mapping-domain-names-w-name-com-and-amazon-route-53/)

Comment: No, because we use a single instance EB server for our website. There is no need for a load balancer since a single instance can easily serve the traffic. Single EB instances are not listed in Route 53 `ALIAS`.

Comment: This is the old "DNS apex cannot contain a CNAME" problem. Amazon Route 53 solves it by allowing apex domains (eg `domain.com`) to point to Elastic Load Balancers, Amazon S3 websites and other DNS entries. Then, `www.domain.com` could be redirected to `domain.com`. However, your situation is the reverse, with `domain.com` pointing at `www.domain.com`. The redirect through S3 then doesn't work with `HTTPS` because it's *your* certificate. How about having your application update a Route 53 `A` record when it boots up, so the domain always points to the right instance?

Comment: in my case i have pointed cname and the domain https://example.com not working  however http://example.com working fine please suggest me how i can make working https://example.com.